# Calculating tangent pointing in a specific 2D Direction

Tags: vector, 3d, normals

I need to calculate the tangent pointing in the same (x,y)-direction as a 2D vector from a given normal.
Here is a visualization:

[Directed Tangent From Normal Viz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4tuF.jpg)

The red plane with the cyan ray is the surface and it's normal,
the green 'Arrow' represents the 2D direction and the blue one the tangent of the normal with the (x,y)-direction of the green arrow.
So when viewing from top (in object space, not surface space) to project onto 2D the green and blue are the same direction.

So if this was too abstract, here is the context:
I'm making a GPU erosion simulation and in order to calculate dissolvation, I need the 3D water velocity vector to test for collision with the terrain normal. But the simulation is in 2D, so I have only a 2D velocity vector.
The paper I'm referencing only notes the program should calculate this 3D vector from the terrain surface tangent and the 2D velocity vector.

Given this information, the normal and the 2D Vector, what is the math to calculate said matching tangent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To calculate the surface tangent, first project the vector onto the normal.

[image]

[image]

Then just add to get the un-normalized tangent.

[image]

To rebuild the reflected velocity, do

[image]

Where `e` is the coefficient of restitution (assuming particles).

Comment: Ok, seem to understand the image above now. So, first step in other 'words': d = -dot (v, n), right? After that I couldn't quite follow... but u seems to be my desired aligned tangent. The last bit doesn't apply for my case as I do not use a particle based simulation but using the shallow-water model. To get the collision 'hardness' it's using a simplified formula that goes like this: length (-n * u); I appreciate it anyway:)

Comment: Oh wait, got it;) Not to hard to get u after all:) Thanks a lot, looking forward to see if it's working!

Comment: be careful to normalize `n`, otherwise your distances will be wrong; suggest you pre-compute these first to avoid doing invsqrt's all the time

Comment: That's not a problem, both n and t should be normalized, they are only used to determine the 'direction' of the collision (I guess), or rather how 'direct' it is. This is then multiplied by the water velocity. The resulting scalar is only used to determine dissolvation of sediment after all, not to respond to collision. It's not physically acurate I suppose but it works:) Thanks!

Comment: no problem; out of curiosity, do you simulate the fluid with e.g. Laplace equation or the full Navier-Stokes? or just some kind of dense VdW gas cloud?

Comment: With relatively simple Euler equations; I'm basically taking reference from [this paper](http://www.cescg.org/CESCG-2011/papers/TUBudapest-Jako-Balazs.pdf) and some others, which implement the shallow water model using virtual pipes to transport water in 2D. I've not yet had the chance to research this field more indepth unfortunately:/

Comment: @Seneral i see it's like a voxel grid method (fig 4)